# Elasticsearch 6.7.0 status Yellow in Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 system installed on a Digital Ocean server. I have installed the Magento 2.3.1 version. I have installed Java and Elasticsearch using the following commands:

**JAVA**

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
```

**ELASTICSEARCH**

```
wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install elasticsearch
Edit this file: /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml and add this info: network.host: localhost
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch
```

If I execute this command:

```
curl -XGET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true
```

This is the result:

```
{
"cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
"status" : "yellow",
"timed_out" : false,
"number_of_nodes" : 1,
"number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
"active_primary_shards" : 20,
"active_shards" : 20,
"relocating_shards" : 0,
"initializing_shards" : 0,
"unassigned_shards" : 20,
"delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
"number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
"number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
"active_shards_percent_as_number" : 50.0
}
```

The status is yellow and unassigned_shards is 20. How can I solve this problem? Please could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Yellow status is due to Shard replication, so you need to create duplicates.  There are various guides on how to set this up.  Note that a yellow status doesnt mean that it wont work as it should, it basically means you dont have any backups